# iris recognition in android

Tags: android

iris recognition technology is possible in android or not.i need the details about that.give me some idea about coding for iris scanner

Answer (score 2):

Smartphone cameras do not have lenses that are good enough to capture an image of the iris close enough and sharp enough to be usable for this.  Moreover, they don't perform well in low light levels, and your users probably won't be happy with you firing the flash at full power at close range into their eyes.

Comment: packages is available in android for iris recognition or not

Comment: No, because as I said above that is impossible with the hardware available.

Comment: impossible is possible in this world. don't comment this like

Comment: In that case I suggest you install libplatitude, and give that a shot.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, although in BETA, but still it is.

You need specific Samsung Device for it.
Specific jar, Specific SDK.

It will work.

Refer below URL's, also for further help make a developer account & you will get the help.

**DEVICE NAME :** Samsung Galaxy Tab Iris SM-T116IR

Documentation URL : https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/samsung-india-identity

For Official documentation : Contact SEAP Customer care, they will fwd you.

Comment: The link is dead and I really need this code fast. Can you please submit a new link.

Comment: @Vimukthi : Link updated in the answer https://seap.samsung.com/sdk/samsung-india-identity

Comment: Try to contact the SEAP team, using your official emailIX, enroll yourself or your company, then they will provide you the key to access the SDK & they will provide you all the sample source codes.

Answer (score -1):

> iris recognition technology is possible in android or not.

NOT.

Even if they were, the technology is flawed.

Comment: SM-T116IR is the device to use